# Express como backend y Angular como frontend en cual de los dos se debe manejar las rutas?

Tags: nodejs, express

Estoy creando un app donde estoy usando Express como backend y Angular como frontend, yo estaba manejando las rutas con express despues decidi instalar angular para desarrollar el frontend, y quiero seguir usando las rutas den express pero no se como hacerlo.. y que me recomiendan donde debo configurar las rutas

Comment: Son dos temas diferentes, pero que coinciden en que express puedes servir paginas html, mientras que en angular, solo transpilas a javascript y html. Generalmente un backend en una estructura tipo "RESTfull" solo te entrega información, y no visual. Por ejemplo, un json con varias propiedades (texto, arreglos, ect). Así que una aplicación de frontend con angular requerirá un servidor apache, nginx o nodejs "servir" el html resultante. El principio de angular sería conectarse a tu backend ( a una ruta establecida en tus routers o el esquema que estés usando) y esta ruta te devolveriá un json.

Comment: Si hablamos de SPA (Angular está diseñado con esto en mente), el navegador nunca "cambia" de ruta, porque ello significaría un nuevo render completo. Por lo tanto, Angular implementa su propio sistema de rutas. Por otro lado, Express maneja sus rutas, que no tienen nada que ver con el sistema de rutas de SPA pero si con *endpoints* que son consumidos por los distintos servicios desde Angular.